# RealmObject instance being invoked multiple times

Tags: android, realm, rx-java, rx-android

I am using Realm + Retrofit2
I am trying to implement following :

1. UI asks DataManger for data.
2. DataManger returns cached data, and checks if data has expired then calls for fresh data.
3. When fresh data is saved in Realm NetworkManager triggers event which is captured by UI for updating data.

**Issue**

When NetworkHelper saves the data in Realm, after commitTransaction() due to onChangeListeners of RealmObjects, the code in DataManger onCall() part is executed again, which again calls NetworkHelper for new data, which subsequently again saves data from the network and process goes into infinite loop. I tried gitHubUser.removeChangeListeners() at multiple points but it still not working. Please point out anything fundamentally being wrong or the correct way to implement with Realm.

Implemented codes are as follows:

**DataManager**

```
 public Observable<GitHubUser> getGitHubUser(final String user){

    return databaseHelper.getGitHubUser(user).doOnNext(new Action1<GitHubUser>() {
        @Override
        public void call(GitHubUser gitHubUser) {
            if(gitHubUser==null || !isDataUpToDate(CACHE_TIME_OUT,gitHubUser.getTimestamp())){
                if(gitHubUser!=null)
                    System.out.println("isDataUpToDate = " + isDataUpToDate(CACHE_TIME_OUT,gitHubUser.getTimestamp()));
                networkHelper.getGitHubUserRxBus(user);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**DataBaseHelper**

```
public Observable<GitHubUser> saveGitHubUser(GitHubUser user, String userId) {
    realmInstance.beginTransaction();
    user.setUserId(userId);
    user.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
    GitHubUser userSaved = realmInstance.copyToRealm(user);
    Observable<GitHubUser> userSavedObservable = userSaved.asObservable();
    realmInstance.commitTransaction();
    return userSavedObservable;
}

public Observable<GitHubUser> getGitHubUser(String user){
    System.out.println("DatabaseHelper.getGitHubUser");
    GitHubUser result = realmInstance.where(GitHubUser.class).contains("userId",user, Case.INSENSITIVE).findFirst();
    if(result != null){
        return result.asObservable();
    }else{
        return Observable.just(null);
    }
}
```

**NetworkHelper**

```
  public void getGitHubUserRxBus(final String user){
    System.out.println("NetworkHelper.getGitHubUserRxBus");
    retroFitService.user(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(new Func1<GitHubUser, Observable<GitHubUser>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<GitHubUser> call(GitHubUser gitHubUser) {
                    System.out.println("NetworkHelper.call");
                    return databaseHelper.saveGitHubUser(gitHubUser,user);
                }
            }).subscribe(new Action1<GitHubUser>() {
        @Override
        public void call(GitHubUser gitHubUser) {

            if (rxBus.hasObservers()) {
                System.out.println("NetworkHelper.call");
                rxBus.send(gitHubUser);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Activity**

```
  subscription.add(dataManager.getGitHubUser("gitHubUserName")
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<GitHubUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
            System.out.println("LoginActivity.call" + " OnComplete");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("throwable = [" + e.toString() + "]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(GitHubUser gitHubUser) {
            System.out.println("LoginActivity.call" + " OnNext");
            if (gitHubUser != null) {
                sampleResponseText.setText(gitHubUser.getName() + " timestamp " + gitHubUser.getTimestamp());
            }
            onCompleted();

        }
    }));
subscription.add(rxBus.toObserverable().subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object o) {
            if(o instanceof GitHubUser){
                GitHubUser gitHubUser = ((GitHubUser)o);
                sampleResponseText.setText(gitHubUser.getName() + " time " + gitHubUser.getTimestamp());
            }
        }
    }));
```

**UPDATE**

Finally Solved it by following in DataManger:

```
return Observable.concat(databaseHelper.getGitHubUser(user).take(1),
                             networkHelper.getGitHubUser(user))
                    .takeUntil(new Func1<GitHubUser, Boolean>() {
                        @Override
                        public Boolean call(GitHubUser gitHubUser) {
                            boolean result = gitHubUser!=null && isDataUpToDate(CACHE_TIME_OUT,gitHubUser.getTimestamp());
                            System.out.println("isDataUpToDate = " + result);
                            return result;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Can you share the code of adding Realm Change listener?

Comment: I haven't added any change listener explicitly to RealmObject. I think it is some default listener which is attached to it.

Comment: That would be strange. Where do you call `DataManger.onCall()`?

Comment: in my activity I call dataManager.getGitHubUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a loop going in your code:

1) You create an observable from a RealmResults in `getGithubUser()`.Realm observables will emit every time you change data that might effect them.

2) You call `networkHelper.getGitHubUserRxBus(user)` after retrieving the user from Realm.

3) When getting a user from the network, you save it to Realm, which will trigger the Observable created in 1) to emit again, which creates your cycle.

To break it, you can do something like `result.asObservable().first()` in `getGitHubUser()` as that will only emit once and then complete, but it depends on your use case if that is acceptable.

Comment: Thanks @Christian : I had solved the problem, hadn't updated the question.   I have updated it now. I guess your solution will also work. Please review update.